# Efficiency limit reached? to "An efficient way to filter out the list elements based on the the elements of the second list"

Tags: list-manipulation

The challenge is following: 
There are two lists `data1` and `data2` of following type:

```
data1 = {{t11,X1},{t12,X2},{t13,X3}, ... ,{t1n,Xn}};
data2 = {{t21,Y1},{t22,Y2},{t23,Y3}, ... ,{t2m,Ym}};
```

The first coordinate in both lists is of the same type, in my case it is time. The second coordinates are different: for example, X is temperature and Y is viscosity. The number of elements in both lists is different: `n ~ 10^4` and  `m ~ 10^7`.

The task is to check whether the temperature was constant through out the whole experiment and filter out the viscosity measurements recorded within +/-10s time windows for all these deviations.

So, a suggested algorithm is following:
1. To check whether condition `Xi == T` is `True` for all elements of `data1`, where `T` is a constant value. 
2. Do nothing if the condition is `True`
3. If the condition is `False` for `i = k`:
 3.1 Determine the `t1k`, 
 3.2 Set up an interval `(t1k-10;t1k+10)`
 3.3 Delete the values `Yi` that were recorded within this interval

I have performed the straightforward solution applying a number of `Do` cycles and `If` type conditions just according to the algorithm. It works but it takes a huge amount of computational time to solve, especially when dealing with large number of lists.

Perhaps there is a more efficient way?

Here is the [link](https://kth.box.com/s/613wjue0kdvkmyucu303umiq8sxrz5mq) for an example data, as requested.

**Comparing calculation times:**

1. Original (slow) solution -- applied to the example data files took 6 min to compute.

   ```
   dataClean = Block[
   {sTfI, loT, datafrmod, xx, T},
   T = 40;

   sTfI = Cases[data1, {_, T}][[{1, -1}, 1]];
   loT = Select[data1, #[[1]] >= sTfI[[1]] && #[[1]] <= sTfI[[2]] &];

   datafrmod = Select[data2, #[[1]] > (loT[[1, 1]] + 5.) && #[[1]]<(loT[[-1, 1]] - 5.) &];
   xx = DeleteDuplicates[
   Select[loT, #[[2]] != T &][[;; , 1]], (Abs[#1 - #2] < 5. &)];

   Do[datafrmod = 
   Join[Select[datafrmod, #[[1]] < (xx[[i]] - 10) &], 
   Select[datafrmod, #[[1]] > (xx[[i]] + 10) &]], {i, Length[xx]}];
   datafrmod
   ]; // AbsoluteTiming
   ```
2. Solution by **Coolwater** was much faster but still took 50 sec to compute.

   ```
   data = Block[
   {T, which},
   T = 40;
   which = 
   With[{tsBad = 
   Extract[data1[[All, 1]], 
   Position[data1[[All, 2]], Except[T], {1}, Heads -> False]]}, 
   Complement[Range[Length[data2]], ##] & @@ 
   Nearest[data2[[All, 1]] -> "Index", tsBad, {\[Infinity], 10}]];
   data2[[which]]
   ]; // AbsoluteTiming
   ```

Is it the limit for the efficiency?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of data? Upload to say Dropbox.

Comment: Wait, so are `data1` and `data2` the same length or not? How is it possible that the time stamps in `data2` run up to `t2n` while the viscosities run up to `Ym`, with `n` and `m` different?

Comment: @SjoerdSmit data1 and data2 are of different length. I have corrected the typo in the description of data1, thanks for pointing out

Comment: Your `data2` time coordinates are a mix of reals and integers. This is why Nearest is slow. Use `Nearest[N @ data2[[All, 1]] -> "Index" , tsBad, {Infinity, 10}]` instead and it will be much faster. Even faster is ``Nearest[Developer`ToPackedArray @ N @ data2[[All, 1]] -> "Index", tsBad, {Infinity, 10}]``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
which = With[{tsBad = Extract[data1[[All, 1]], Position[data1[[All, 2]], Except[T], {1}, Heads -> False]]},
           Complement[Range[Length[data2]], ##] & @@ Nearest[data2[[All, 1]] -> "Index", tsBad, {∞, 10}]];

data3 = data2[[which]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a readable approach based on your example data

```
data1 = Import["data1.dat"];
data2 = Import["data2.dat"];
```

Let's inspect your data.

```
data1[[;; , 2]] // Union
```

> ```
> {20, 26, 40, 41}
> ```

There seems to be only 4 values for the temperature ever read.

```
data1[[;; , 2]] // Commonest
```

> ```
> {40}
> ```

Seems like the normal, stable temperature is 40. So we want to get rid of any datapoints within 10 seconds of the temperature not being 40. Let's get a list of the bad temperature readings.

```
bad = Position[data1, {_, Except[40]}] // Flatten // data1[[#]] &
```

> ```
> {{2.0013,20},{4.9991,20},{6.9999,20},{8.9999,20},{11.9998,20},<<85>>,
>  {38772.4,41},{38775.2,41},{38778.1,41},{41814.,41}}
> ```

Let's generate the conditions for the datapoints to be discarded based on the time.

```
condition = (Or @@ (# - 10 < x && x < # + 10 & @@@ bad) // Simplify) /. x -> #
List @@ condition // Short
```

> ```
> {-7.9987<#1<45.9995,895.008<#1<915.008,1797.05<#1<1834.05,
>  <<19>>,38759.6<#1<38788.1,41804.<#1<41824.}
> ```

Replacing `x` with `Slot` (`#`) has to do with working around MMA's scoping.

There's a lot of data to deal with, let's make this into a compiled function:

```
compiledTest = 
 With[{condition = condition}, 
  Compile[x, If[condition &@x, 1., 0.], 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True]]
```

Slowest part of the procedure:

```
 picker = compiledTest[data2[[;; , 1]]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {2.01518, Null}
> ```

```
 (filteredData2 = Pick[data2, picker, 0.];) // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.161324, Null}
> ```

```
Length@filteredData2
Length@data2
```

> ```
> 2476550
> 2514200
> ```

Finally:

```
badData2 = Pick[data2, picker, 1.];
ListPlot[{filteredData2[[;; ;; 100]], badData2}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

> [image]

It doesn't look like there was much to gain from filtering in the first place. Looks like you have quite some issues with digital noise.